# How to handle dynamic Elements in Dropdown in Java Selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I want to select a values in dropdown. and my problem is. I can't locate the specific element as they are dynamic and they will just appear in the inspect elements Once I choose a value in dropdown.

and I can't right click and inspect element the values in dropdown when the dropdown is open as it will close as soon as I left click.

I also can't use "Select" class as they are embedded in "div" html element

I also can't use "SendKeys" as the dropdown don't have textfield

Here are the codes I tried to use.

```
//try #1
        driver.findElement(dropDown).click();
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        ((WebElement) js.executeScript("document.getElementById('dropwDownID).value='VALUE I WANT'")).click();
```

note: when I tried this script("document.getElementById('dropwDownID).value='VALUE I WANT') in the console,  it returns the value I want.

```
//try #2
        driver.findElement(dropDown).click();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(this_Element_Only_Appear_When_I_Choose_A_Value));
```

[Please see attached picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYRbE.png)

Comment: You need to freeze DOM to be able to inspect the options.

Comment: Hi pburgr, it works! I was able to click the element I want. thankyou so much!